# Using hapijs with Rest Client in Webstorm 10.0 to create a POST method and test it

Tags: javascript, mongodb, rest, webstorm, hapi.js

I'm trying to build a route for the POST method and test that it works with the Rest Client made available in Webstorm 10.0. I've read the API and many stackOverflow questions on hapijs and rest client regarding this. I've gotten the route for the GET method built and successfully tested. I'm struggling with post though, in particular, reading in the payload and submitting requests through the rest client. Basically, I'm trying to send in a car object that has the form `{brand:'brandName'}` in the mongodb database for example `{"_id": ObjectId("aisjdioajsoidj"), "brand": "Kia"}` shows up in mongodb shell.

This is what I've gotten so far for the route:

```
server.route({
method: 'POST', 
path: '/{type}/{brand}', //only designed to post cars types currently
handler: function(request,reply){ 
    var postPayload = request.payload; //even after I submit text through the rest client postPayload never takes on request.payloads value. Also, request.payload is a string that can't be converted to an object with JSON.parse()
    var postPromise;
    dao1.create2('car',request.payload); //I send the payload to my data access object to handle it, where the post request can be validated with JSON schema for 'car'
    //postPromise = users.insert({brand:request.payload}) this works but, i can't validate request.payload with JSON schema
}
});
```

This is the code I have for my data access object for POST:

```
var DAO = function(){ //dao1 is an instance of DAO
    this.create2 = function(schema, input){ //this method works fine when I hardcode in the input with something like {brand:"Kia"} so it's clearly getting the wrong type of data
        this.errors = env.validate(schema, input);
        this.promise;
        if (!this.errors) {
            if(schema=='car'){
                this.promise = users.insert(input,function(error, results){ //this is a method from monk (an npm package for mongodb)
                    if(error){
                        console.log("Error 400 Bad Request "+error);
                }
                    else{
                        console.log("User's car validated"+JSON.stringify(results));
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Perhaps my issue is with how I've been interacting with the Rest Client. I added `Content-Type: application/json` to the request headers. To submit a post request I entered `"{"brand":"Toyota2.3"}"` into the text field under the request body section. I've also tried `car={"brand":"Toyota2.3"}` both show up in the debugger like `"{"brand":"Toyota2.3"}"`. However when I put request.payload into the validator I get the error `{ validation: { type: 'object' } }`. I seem to have no way to convert this information to an object. Also note, I set the method to POST in the debugger, filled in the host/port with `http://localhost:8000` and I filled in the path with `/car/Kia` (which all worked for when I added the GET route). My thoughts, is there anyway to convert `request.payload` to an object? or am I using the rest client incorrectly? perhaps I am missing  I would appreciate advice, thanks!

Comment: Have you tried any other client such as POSTMAN?

Comment: No, perhaps it is worth a try.

Comment: Were you able to solve your problem?

Comment: I was able to effectively debug it with Postman. Still couldn't figure out Rest's version. Thanks for the assistance!